# How to generate second EAR with sources

Tags: eclipse, maven, maven-3, ear, maven-source-plugin

I have a project that consist of multiple modules (ejb's, jar's, war's) and I'm using a pom.xml of type "ear" to package them. It works perfectly fine and it generates an EAR-file with the correct jar's / etc. 
What I additionally need is a second EAR-file with source code of included modules... I tried to use the source plugin as follow but the generated EAR didn't include any sources:

```
            <plugin>
                <groupId>org.apache.maven.plugins</groupId>
                <artifactId>maven-source-plugin</artifactId>
                <executions>
                    <execution>
                        <id>attach-sources</id>
                        <goals>
                            <goal>jar</goal>
                        </goals>
                    </execution>
                </executions>
            </plugin>
```

Funnily enough when I run "install" on my parent pom.xml, where all modules are included, the %MODULE_NAME%-sources.jar files are generated in my local maven repository. Is it possible to somehow reuse them and package into a second EAR?

Comment: An EAR with sources does not make sense, cause this can't be deployed into JEE container. You can create a jar with the sources. Apart from that a EAR module should not having source files at all.

Comment: You are right! Hmm is it possible to create some other archive (i.e. jar) with Maven that contains modules that are included in the EAR?

Comment: You mean a jar or war module ? Yes.

Comment: jar would be sufficient. I just need to create an archive with all the modules and their sources. Any tip how to do it?

Comment: I would suggest to take a look at the [maven-assembly-plugin](http://maven.apache.org/plugins/maven-assembly-plugin/) and the [maven-dependency-plugin](http://maven.apache.org/plugins/maven-dependency-plugin/sources-mojo.html) to got the source packages.

Comment: I've tried to use maven-dependency-plugin but it gives me error for my "war" modules because they don't consist sources classifier:
`<configuration>
        <artifactItems>
         <artifactItem>
          <groupId>${project.groupId}</groupId>
          <artifactId>${project.artifactId}</artifactId>
          <version>${project.version}</version>
          <type>${project.packaging}</type>
          <classifier>sources</classifier>          
         </artifactItem>
        </artifactItems>
        <outputDirectory>../PKM-parent/target/dependencies</outputDirectory>
       </configuration>`

Comment: with this setup you would like to add the sources of your own project where i assume you don't create the sources packages. Take a look at the maven-sources-plugin.